# php insert data in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, joomla3.0

I have created a php function that creates thumbnails and it works as suposed but now I want to insert this thumbnail image and some data in mymysqli data baze. I tryed to do this but it does not work. I am not good to mysql and need help.

```
require 'config.php';

if(preg_match('/[.](jpg)$/', $filename)) {
    $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($path_to_image_directory . $filename);
} else if (preg_match('/[.](gif)$/', $filename)) {
    $im = imagecreatefromgif($path_to_image_directory . $filename);
} else if (preg_match('/[.](png)$/', $filename)) {
    $im = imagecreatefrompng($path_to_image_directory . $filename);
}

$ox = imagesx($im);
$oy = imagesy($im);

$nx = $final_width_of_image;
$ny = floor($oy * ($final_width_of_image / $ox));

$nm = imagecreatetruecolor($nx, $ny);

imagecopyresized($nm, $im, 0,0,0,0,$nx,$ny,$ox,$oy);

if(!file_exists($path_to_thumbs_directory)) {
  if(!mkdir($path_to_thumbs_directory)) {
       die("There was a problem. Please try again!");
  } 
   }
imagejpeg($nm, $path_to_thumbs_directory . $filename);
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'timoleon_pandess';
$pass = 'pass';
mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
mysql_select_db('timoleon_pandessia');

$insert_path="INSERT INTO `ng17p_jshopping_products`(`product_id`,      `parent_id`, `product_ean`, `product_availability`, `product_template`,  `product_price`, `min_price`, `different_prices`, `product_weight`, `image`) VALUES ([value-1],[value-2],[value-3],[value-4],[value-5],[value-6],[value-7],[value-8],[value-9],[value-10])";

$var=mysql_query($inser_path);
?>
```

Comment: Tagged as mysqli, but you are using mysql ? Might wanne go with mysqli now or PDO...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use ob_start(); ob_get_clean(); to get the image content and put it in your database.

First create a field in you database to store image content :

```
ALTER TABLE `ng17p_jshopping_products` ADD `image_content` LONGBLOB NOT NULL ;
```

And use your code like this :

```
<?php
require 'config.php';

if(preg_match('/[.](jpg)$/', $filename)) {
    $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($path_to_image_directory . $filename);
} else if (preg_match('/[.](gif)$/', $filename)) {
    $im = imagecreatefromgif($path_to_image_directory . $filename);
} else if (preg_match('/[.](png)$/', $filename)) {
    $im = imagecreatefrompng($path_to_image_directory . $filename);
}

$ox = imagesx($im);
$oy = imagesy($im);

$nx = $final_width_of_image;
$ny = floor($oy * ($final_width_of_image / $ox));

$nm = imagecreatetruecolor($nx, $ny);

imagecopyresized($nm, $im, 0,0,0,0,$nx,$ny,$ox,$oy);

if(!file_exists($path_to_thumbs_directory)) {
  if(!mkdir($path_to_thumbs_directory)) {
       die("There was a problem. Please try again!");
  } 
}

$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'timoleon_pandess';
$pass = 'pass';
mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
mysql_select_db('timoleon_pandessia');

ob_start();
imagejpeg($nm);
$image_content = mysql_real_escape_string(base64_encode(ob_get_clean()));
imagedestroy($nm);

$insert_path="INSERT INTO `ng17p_jshopping_products`(`product_id`, `parent_id`, `product_ean`, `product_availability`, `product_template`,  `product_price`, `min_price`, `different_prices`, `product_weight`, `image`,`image_content`) VALUES ([value-1],[value-2],[value-3],[value-4],[value-5],[value-6],[value-7],[value-8],[value-9],[value-10],'".$image_content."')";

$var=mysql_query($inser_path);
mysql_close();
?>
```

To show your image, you have to use a function like this one :

```
<?php
function show_image($id) {
    $host = 'localhost';
    $user = 'timoleon_pandess';
    $pass = 'pass';
    mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
    mysql_select_db('timoleon_pandessia');

    // code to retrieve the image from database with $id id to $image_to_show variable
    // ....

    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    echo stripslashes(base64_decode($image_to_show["image_content"]));
}
?>
```

Comment: My answer is for storing image content Into Database and not on disk. If you want to store file path of the image you have to store the name of the file "$path_to_thumbs_directory . $filename" into mysql field...

Answer (score 0):

Put in DB path to image eg: '\img\image2.png'

Change in table to Type "longb" (which will trigger LONGBLOB) for store images.
Read this 
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,17671,27914

Why you want to insert image in DB? 
Do like this

```
   Insert into table (`path`) Values ('image.png');
```

`\image.png` - path to image on server. When read from DB you van add full path `\img\avatar\image.png`

I don't understand, you use insert query like is written in php? The value is need to encapse in '' eg: not `,[value-4]` but `,'[value-4]'`. And value will be a  variable `$value4` I think.

```
  INSERT INTO `ng17p_jshopping_products` (`product_id`,    `parent_id`, `product_ean`, `product_availability`, `product_template`,  `product_price`, `min_price`, `different_prices`, `product_weight`, `image`) VALUES ('[value-1]','[value-2]','[value-3]','[value-4]','[value-5]','[value-6]','[value-7]','[value-8]','[value-9]','[value-10]')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add variable witch will contain filename of image.

```
$filename=$path_to_thumbs_directory.$filename;
```

When insert

```
$query="INSERT INTO `ng17p_jshopping_products` (`product_id`,`parent_id`,`product_ean`, `product_availability`,`product_template`, `product_price`, `min_price`, `different_prices`, `product_weight`, `image`) VALUES ('[value-1]','[value-2]','[value-3]','[value-4]','[value-5]','[value-6]','[value-7]','[value-8]','[value-9]','$filename')";
$res=mysql_query($query);
if($res==1) { $id=mysql_insert_id;
$query="Select image from ng17p_jshopping_products where id='$id'";
$res=mysql_query($query);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($res);
echo 'It is OK <img src="'.$row['image'].'">'; 
} else echo 'Error';
```

If you make done all and it will work when try to change code to use mysql**i**, read here `http://php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqli.php`

Comment: I made the changes but it does not work... any idea where must be the problem?$host = 'localhost';
 $user = 'timoleon_pandess';
 $pass = 'pass';

 mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);

 mysql_select_db('timoleon_pandessia');
 $im = imagecreatefromgif($path_to_image_directory . $filename);
 $insert_path="INSERT INTO      `ng17p_jshopping_products_images`(`image_id`, `product_id`, `image_name`, `image`) VALUES ('[999]','[998]','$filename', '$im')";
 
 $var=mysql_query($inser_path);

Answer (score 0):

This is enough to make connection between item with it's image. Set to cell in witch you store path to image to varchar(255) not blob or other like in another case (store file not on hard disk but in DB )

```
$bd_host="localhost"; 
$bd_user="timoleon_pandess";
$bd_password="pass";
$bd_base="_base";

$con=mysql_connect($bd_host, $bd_user, $bd_password); 

if(!con) {
echo 'Ошибка, невозможно подключиться к серверу базы данных.'; 
exit; 
}

mysql_select_db($bd_base, $con); 
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');

$filename='/img/img.png'; // you need to catch it when you make and save thumbnail

$query="insert into ng17p_jshopping_products (`image`) Values ('$filename')";
mysql_query($query);
```

If your script not make image or save it where is needed, this is another problem!